# Distributional derivatives on hypersurface?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

In a paper I was reading, the define a set $Q=(0,T)\times \Omega$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain, and then they write
$$\langle \frac{d}{dt}u - \Delta u, \varphi \rangle_{\mathcal D^*(Q), \mathcal D(Q)} = -\langle u, \frac{d}{dt}u \rangle - \langle u, \Delta \varphi\rangle$$
where $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(Q)$ and the duality pairing on the LHS here is between $\mathcal{D}^*(Q)$ and $\mathcal{D}(Q)$. I guess this is just using the definition of the distributional derivatives $D_1, ... ,D_n$ and $D_t$.

Suppose now that $\Gamma$ is a hypersurface and set $S=(0,T)\times \Gamma$. Does the following make sense in some way:
$$\langle \frac{d}{dt}u - \Delta_\Gamma u, \varphi \rangle_{\mathcal D^*(S), \mathcal D(S)} = -\langle u, \frac{d}{dt}u \rangle - \langle u, \Delta_\Gamma \varphi\rangle$$
where $\Delta_\Gamma$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator not the standard Laplacian. How to make this rigourous and precise? I tried searching for distributions on manifolds but that means something else it seems. Any references to this topic are appreciated.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669379/about-a-function-space-on-bigcup-t-in-0-t-gammat-times-t?noredirect=1#comment1406810_669379

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the definition of distributional derivatives.

The book "Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds" by Grigoryan (I can even access that part as a free preview on books.google.com) contains formula (7.30): locally integrable function $u(t,x)$ satisfies the heat equation on a manifold $N=(0,\infty)\times M$ in a distributional sense if and only if for every $\varphi \in {\cal D}' (N)$ it holds:
$$\left( u, \partial_t \varphi + \triangle_\mu \varphi \right)=0.$$
This is transformed (using Fubini's theorem) in the form (7.31)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \left( u, \partial_t \varphi\right)_{L^2(M)}dt
+\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \left( u, \triangle_\mu \varphi\right)_{L^2(M)}dt=0.$$
The point in using $L^2$ inner product instead of a duality pairing lies in the fact that for every $t>0$ the solution is a smooth function, no matter what the initial data are. Frankly, I don't understand all the technical details, however, that book might be a worthy reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote does make perfect sense, as integration by parts on a sufficiently smooth manifold $S$ is permissible. Note that you have made a little mistake, and this is the correct version
$$
\left\langle \frac{d}{dt}u - \Delta_\Gamma u, \varphi \right\rangle_{\mathscr D^*(S), \mathscr D(S)} = -\left\langle u, \frac{d}{dt}\varphi \right\rangle - \langle u, \Delta_\Gamma \varphi\rangle.
$$
In particular
$$
\langle \Delta_\Gamma u,v \rangle=-\langle \nabla_\Gamma u,\nabla_\Gamma v \rangle,
$$
even for $v\in H_0^1(S)$ and $u\in H^{-1}(S)$. A good reference is:

Emmanuel Hebey, *[Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds: Sobolev Spaces and Inequalities.](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=clnseries&ikey=CLN-5)*